# Specific Row in a Group with a Max Value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, max

I have the following **SQL SERVER** table:

```
+--------+-------+-------+------+
| Person | Phone | Count | Rank |
+--------+-------+-------+------+
|   A    |   X   |   1   |  1   |
|   B    |   X   |   9   |  2   |
|   C    |   X   |   5   |  3   |
|   T    |   Y   |   6   |  1   |
|   S    |   Y   |   2   |  2   |
+--------+-------+-------+------+
```

I need the result to be the **Person** and **Phone** value where the **Rank** is equal to 1, but the **MAX** count value for the specific Phone for example:

```
+--------+-------+----------+------+
| Person | Phone | MaxCount | Rank |
+--------+-------+----------+------+
|   A    |   X   |     9    |  1   |
|   T    |   Y   |     6    |  1   |
+--------+-------+----------+------+
```

I can join on the table twice but was wondering if I can use **MAX** to achieve this?

Comment: You know that you can also use `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Phone ORDER BY ID)` to get the `Rank` "column"?

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted... any ideas?

Comment: I haven't downvoted it and i don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT T.Person, T.Phone, (SELECT MAX(Count) 
                           FROM YourTable AS TI 
                           WHERE TI.Phone = T.Phone) AS MaxCount, T.[Rank]
FROM YourTable AS T
WHERE T.[RANK] = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bb3e9/3/0)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MAX(Count)OVER(PARTITION BY Phone)`, for example with a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Person, 
           Phone, 
           MaxCount = MAX(Count)OVER(PARTITION BY Phone), 
           Rank
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT  Person, 
        Phone, 
        MaxCount, 
        Rank
FROM CTE
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use `outer apply` like this:

```
SELECT Person, 
       Phone, 
       MaxCount,
       [Rank]
FROM YourTable t1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX([count]) AS MaxCount FROM YourTable WHERE Phone = t1.Phone) oa
WHERE [Rank] = 1
```